# Estimating discretization step from noisy timeseries

Tags: statistics, time-series

We have a sensor that measures some physical process that sends the value via PWM. As the sensor discretize the data, when reading the PWM signal we should only see the value in discrete steps. For example, when the signal varies from 200 to 400, we will not see  all possible values between 200 and 400, but rather values like `200 225 250 ... 375 400`  indicating the discretization step of 25.

However our PWM reader is noisy resulting in values like `198 224 261 275` etc. What is the correct way to estimate the discretization step and parameters of the noise assuming the noise is Gaussian?

I suppose we can just enumerate all the possible steps, then for each step calculate reminders of values divided by the step. Then the discretization step should be the step when the remainders produce the best fit to Gaussian. For the best fit I suppose we can take the least sum of minimal squares from the Gaussian based on reminders.

The obvious problem with this naive approach is that both `step` and `step / 2` may produce the same fit. That can be taken care I suppose by reducing a possible step range based on some guess. But perhaps this naive approach based on remainders is not the proper way to deal with the problem?

In our case typical histogram of data points is given bellow. As we suspect that the step and parameters of the noise depend on environmental conditions we prefer not to mix data from different runs limiting the data amount.

```
value   count
682     2
775     8
776     14
807     7
838     3
868     1
869     2
900     1
931     3
993     2
1024    2
1055    2
1117    3
1179    2
1210    1
1241    1
1272    2
1303    1
1334    1
1365    2
1397    1
1427    1
1428    2
1458    1
1521    2
1551    1
1552    1
1583    1
1614    1
1645    1
1676    1
1707    3
1738    1
1769    1
1800    2
1831    1
1862    3
1893    1
1924    2
1955    1
1986    2
2047    1
2048    2
2079    1
2111    1
2141    1
2142    1
2173    1
2204    2
2234    1
2235    2
2266    1
2297    1
2325    1
2359    2
2390    3
2483    3
2514    2
2545    1
2575    1
2607    2
2638    3
2669    1
2731    4
2762    2
2794    2
2823    1
2825    1
2854    1
2858    1
2889    1
2918    2
2980    3
3011    2
3042    2
3071    1
3073    1
3104    2
3134    2
3135    1
3197    3
3228    1
3259    1
3287    1
3289    1
3290    2
3321    2
3351    1
3352    2
3383    1
3414    1
3445    4
3506    1
3508    3
3539    1
3570    3
3601    2
3630    1
3632    1
3661    1
3663    2
3694    2
3723    1
3725    2
3754    2
3756    2
3785    16
3787    7
3818    45
3820    1
3822    1
3825    2
3849    3
3880    2
3911    1
3942    3
3971    1
3973    2
4002    1
4004    2
4035    5
4095    1
4097    3
4128    2
4152    1
4157    2
4191    2
4220    1
4222    1
4251    1
4253    3
4276    1
4313    1
4315    4
4344    1
4346    3
4375    3
4377    4
```

Comment: Great question, however, it's off topic here since it's not about a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, to do this carefully, you'll want to separate the likelihood function (what you can extract from the data) and the prior (what you know about the variable in question apart from the data), and combine the two by multiplying pointwise; this is a Bayesian approach. You evaluate the likelihood by enumerating the possible values and seeing how well they fit. The prior encompasses considerations such as, the step is at least n0 and not more than n1.

Comment: It seems likely that the distribution of observed steps around a true value is probably non-Gaussian; this will affect how you evaluate the likelihood. If you want to be very careful, you could arrange a hierarchical model, such that different data sets have different but related parameters. Being very careful could be computationally burdensome (or maybe not); it's often the case that there are pretty good approximations which look like simple heuristics of the kind you mentioned, but in order to know what simple approximations are applicable, ideally you go through the whole process.

Comment: Thanks, I will post to stats. Initially I was planning to give Julia code, but then I realized that then problem is not so much language-related, but more general...